# php generated image disapears after loading

Tags: php, image

I used this code to resize my image:

```
if ($height > $width) {
  $divisor = $width / $imgs;
} else {
  $divisor = $height / $imgs;
}

$resizedWidth   = ceil($width / $divisor);
$resizedHeight  = ceil($height / $divisor);


$xOffset = floor(($resizedWidth  - $imgs) / 2);
$yOffset = floor(($resizedHeight - $imgs) / 2);                                        

$resized  = imagecreatetruecolor($resizedWidth, $resizedHeight);
$thumb    = imagecreatetruecolor($imgs, $imgs);
imagecopyresized($resized, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resizedWidth, $resizedHeight, $width, $height);
imagecopyresized($thumb, $resized, 0, 0, $xOffset, $yOffset, $imgs, $imgs, $imgs, $imgs);
imagepng($thumb, "test.png");           
$instr = fopen("test.png","rb");  
$imageThumb = addslashes(fread($instr,filesize("test.png")));
```

Landscape works fine, but when I upload portraits, the Thumbnail gets loaded until it is full seen, then it disappears.

Comment: what is the value of `$imgs` ?

Comment: The thumbnail size. 175 fe. it should be square.

Comment: check Apache ( or your web server's error log ). May have something interesting.

Comment: fe. = for example: 175px

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$title"); 
header("Content-length: $size"); 
header("Content-type: $type"); 
echo $image;
```

It's was a matter of $size. -.-

Make sure you use right data!

PS: Why it works in different orientations? …thats confused me.

Comment: "It's was a matter of $size." - That was the last statement of my last boyfriend!